# Multiple entity managers and connections config on separate files

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to work with multiple database connections and entity managers that are set dynamically.

Is there anyway I can inject new configurations to the `config.yml` file so Symfony will be aware of new connections and entity managers at runtime?

Or even store those configurations in separate files and import them?

Comment: From where comes the configuration?