# Multiple connections and entity managers in a symfony 2 / 3 application

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, multi-tenant

My multi-tenant-app uses a master database, that holds information about tenants (like name, etc.) and a app-specific database **per tenant**.

I configured a *master* and *some_tenant* connection and entity manager in the doctrine section inside config.yml.

This gives me access to the master database from a controller (eg. for validating and getting tenant information for **some_tenant** based on the subdomain **some_tenant.my-app.com**). And it lets me use a tenant-specific database and entity manager during the application life-cycle.

The doctrine section in my config looks like this:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: 'master'
    connections:
        master:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        some_tenant:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host_some_tenant%"
            port:     "%database_port_some_tenant%"
            dbname:   "%database_name_some_tenant%"
            user:     "%database_user_some_tenant%"
            password: "%database_password_some_tenant%"
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        master:
            connection: master
            mappings:
                BEMultiTenancyBundle: ~
        some_tenant:
            connection: some_tenant
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
```

**Here comes the part, which I am unhappy with and cannot find a solution:**

First of all, tenants will be more than 20. And it starts to get messy, altering the doctrine config this way.
Then there is another config file, called tenants.yml which holds more information like enabled/disabled app-features, tenant-specific themes, etc.

The file is loaded, validated using the [Config Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config.html), and a container parameter is set, so that tenants configurations are available app-wide.
I would like to store the database credentials also in that file.

1. I want to create connections and entity managers based on that config. One per each tenant, which can be used during the app life-cycle.
2. I need to have them available also at the console command `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --em=some_tenant` for updating each tenant's database schem and `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --em=master` for updating the master database scheme.

By now I guess, the only way to achieve this is to add configuration parameters to the doctrine section programmatically **after** the AppBundle is loaded, and **before** the doctrine registry is constructed with the given managers and connections.

But I cannot even find a point, where I could achive this.

Is there another way to get to point 1 and 2?

Even though there is a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884040/multiple-entity-managers-and-connections-config-on-separate-files), which I am not sure if it is exactly about the same problem and is about 3 years old, I wanted to post this question with a bit more explanation.

Comment: Will each tenant database have the same schema and entities?

Comment: yes. and the schema and mappings are defined in the \AppBundle\Entity namespace.

Comment: One option would be to make a console command which will generate your doctrine.yml config file based on tenants.yml.  That at least would eliminate some of the manual steps of adding a new tenant.  Otherwise, all I can suggest is looking at the RegisterMappingsPass in the Doctrine Bridge and see if you can do something similar.

Comment: Hm. The approach is totally not, what i was looking for, but does what I want to achieve. Thank you! I didn't think about generating the configuration part programmatically. This will be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in comments is a straight way easy solution and it will work. The other solution I've ever meet is to dynamically replace tenant database credentails using some external conditions, i.e request `HOST`.

You can decorate or extend the connection factory with a service in a way, that having the request stack available (or providing the domain with ENV or console argument for other SAPI's) you can have the same entity manager (even `default`!) being configured on demand.

on a brief look this would look like

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory;    
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class DynamicConnectionFactory extends Factory 
{
   /** @var RequestStack */
   private $requestStack;

   public function __construct(array $types, RequestStack $stack)
   {
       parent::__construct($types);
       $this->requestStack = $stack;
   }

   public function createConnection(array $params, Configuration $config = null, EventManager $eventManager = null, array $mappingTypes = array())
   {
       $host = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getHost();
       $params = $this->replaceParamsForHost(array $params, $host);
       return parent::createConnection($params, $config, $eventManager, $mappingTypes);
   }

   private function replaceParamsForHost(array $params, $host)
   {
       //do your magic, i.e parse config or call Memcache service or count the stars
       return array_replace($params, ['database' => $host]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this slim solution. With this dynamic approach (of using just one configured connection and replacing the current one with the one that is needed), i would have to extend the existing doctrine:schema:update command, to maintain different db schemes for each tenant. Hence I chose Cerad's way, and created the doctrine configuration with a console command based on the tenant's configuration, which works perfectly.

Comment: If your schemas are very different yes, config is the only way

Answer (score 0):

I think that, To manage multi-tenant with symfony 2/3.
We can config `auto_mapping: false` for ORM of doctrine.
file: config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: master
        connections:
            master:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%master_database_host%'
                port:     '%master_database_port%'
                dbname:   '%master_database_name%'
                user:     '%master_database_user%'
                password: '%master_database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            tenant:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%tenant_database_host%'
                port:     '%tenant_database_port%'
                dbname:   '%tenant_database_name%'
                user:     '%tenant_database_user%'
                password: '%tenant_database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: master
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            master:
                connection: master
                auto_mapping: false
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Resources/master/config/doctrine
            tenant:
                connection: tenant
                auto_mapping: false
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Resources/tenant/config/doctrine
```

After that, we cannot handle connection of each tenant by override connection info in request_listener like article: http://mohdhallal.github.io/blog/2014/09/12/handling-multiple-entity-managers-in-doctrine-the-smart-way/
I hope that, this practice can help someone working with multi-tenant

Regards,
Vuong Nguyen